# Django Polls App: Background Image Not Loading

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am learning Django and building out the first test poll app but am running into issues with the background images. The green text works, but adding the background image does not do anything (background is just white). Any idea why this is not functioning properly?

Background Image C:\Users\xxx\Python\Django\mysite\polls\static\polls\images\sample123.jpg

Style CSS: C:\Users\xxx\Python\Django\mysite\polls\static\polls\style.css

```css
li a {
    color: blue;
}

body {
        background: url('C:\Users\xxx\Python\Django\mysite\polls\static\polls\images\sample123.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
         }
```

Index HTML: C:\Users\xxxx\Python\Django\mysite\polls\templates\polls

```html
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
body {
        background: url('/static/images/sample123.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
         }
```

Comment: This did not work for me... I also updated the text color in my sample from green to blue to confirm the file itself is being loaded (which worked). I tried this and also tried adding the full path for my url. Why is my background still showing white?

Answer (score 0):

Your background image is not rendering because, for the background image, you are providing the relative path.
Either provide the absolute path or use a static template tag.

```
body {
    background: white url({%static 'polls\images\sample123.jpg'%}) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me... I also updated the text color in my sample from green to blue to confirm the file itself is being loaded (which worked). I tried this and also tried adding the full path for my url. Why is my background still showing white?

Comment: use background-image property instead of background. And toggle no-repeat: property that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `polls/urls.py` file

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    #....
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) #with out this, the images will not be displayed
```

and this in your `polls/settings.py` file

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-image: url("C:\Users\xxx\Python\Django\mysite\polls\static\polls\style.css") no-repeat;
```